# send whole table data to another table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table I'm trying to send the whole date from this table to another table but it's not working what is the problem?

```
 $selectQry = "select * from  tbl_temp_order";
$getData = mysqli_query(getConnection(), $selectQry);
$id = getId();
$done="";
while ($row = $getData->fetch_assoc()) {
    $addData = "insert into tbl_perm_order(orderId,fId,tId,qty,servantName)values (?,?,?,?,?)";
     $st = getConnection()->prepare($addData);
     $st->bind_param('iiiis', $id, $row['fId'],$row['tId'],$row['qty'],$row['servantName']);
     $st->execute();
     $done = mysqli_query(getConnection(), $addData);
 }
 if ($done) {
     $deleteQry = "delete from tbl_temp_order";
     mysqli_query(getConnection(), $deleteQry);
 }
```

[image: After pressing (send order) I want it to send all the data to another table and truncate current table]

Comment: Put the above code into a function and re-use on another table(s)

Comment: imo instead of using two tables add a column called `status`, then just flag this order as sent, 0 being new, 1 being pending, 2 being sent, 3 being returned, 4 being staff, etc etc. then Just plop `status = 0` on the queries to grab the different types. also it should be `orders` which contain relationship links to customer table and details about the order, then a table with all the items in called `orders_items`, which contain the actual line items.

Comment: I'm supporting @B001ᛦ suggestion and in addition I would suggest to use smarty as template engine and preparing data using one php function and assigning the output of function to smarty, then use it in template as many times as you need. One function - many uses in smarty template.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a query like this

table2 fields are (T2Field1, T2Field2),

table1 fields are (T1Field1, T1Field2)

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT T2Field1 as T1Field1, T2Field2 as T1Field2  FROM table1 
DELETE FROM table1
```

This query will move your data from table1 to table2 and at the end delete all data from the table1, without loop and complicated codes